# How to get activity object in QT5.2?

Tags: qt, android-activity

I have tried the fellowing two methods but failed:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");



  QPlatformNativeInterface *interface = QApplication::platformNativeInterface();
    jobject activity = (jobject)interface->nativeResourceForIntegration("QtActivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was in QT 5.2 and this worked for me:

first:

in your .pro:

```
QT += gui-private
```

now in your cpp:

```
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#include <qpa/qplatformnativeinterface.h>


QAndroidJniObject getMainActivity()
{
    QPlatformNativeInterface *interface =  QApplication::platformNativeInterface();
   QAndroidJniObject activity = (jobject)interface->nativeResourceForIntegration("QtActivity");

   if(!activity.isValid())
           qDebug()<<"CLASS NOT VALID!!!!!!!!";
   else
           qDebug()<<"HORRAY!";

return activity;
```